# Build file .aab is FAILED

Tags: android, http, release, android-app-bundle

I can't build *.aab* release file.
The project is old, and written in **Java**.

```
compileSdkVersion 33

buildToolsVersion '33.0.1'

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.0'

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
}
```

After generate I got the next error:

`:app:minifyReleaseWithR8 FAILED`

`Unexpected reference to missing service class: META-INF/services/javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory.`

`Unexpected reference to missing service class: META-INF/services/javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory.`

`Unexpected reference to missing service class: META-INF/services/javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory.`

`Library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient implements program class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient`

[image]

How to fix it?

How to build a file *.aab/.apk* without this error?

Thanks.